# Unity2d Scale background and game bounds to screen size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am building a 2D game in Unity, and struggle with the background and the bounds.

In the game, the player can move left and right inside the screen bounds. On the left and right bounds are walls that blocks the player.

But I don't know how I can get the position of those bounds, and how I can make the background fit.

All I understand is that the camera's height is constant and the width changes based on the aspect-ratio.
And I have found this code that scales the background image to fit the width:

```cs
private void Awake()
{
    float cameraHeight = camera.orthographicSize * 2;
    Vector2 cameraSize = new Vector2(camera.aspect * cameraHeight, cameraHeight);
    Vector2 spriteSize = spriteRenderer.sprite.bounds.size;
    
    Vector2 scale = transform.localScale;
    if (cameraSize.x >= cameraSize.y) { // Landscape (or equal)
        scale *= cameraSize.x / spriteSize.x;
    } else { // Portrait
        scale *= cameraSize.y / spriteSize.y;
    }
    transform.position = Vector2.zero;
    transform.localScale = scale;
}
```

It works, but the bottom part (where the ground is drawn) is sometimes outside of the screen.

And I still don't know how to add the walls to the edges of the screen to make sure the player doesn't exit the screen's bounds.

I know this is probably simple and a well answered question, but I am new to 2D development.

I searched online, and watched tutorials for 2D games but wasn't able to find anything that references or talks about that.